# Proof of log 2 base 10 value

Tags: logarithms

Is there a way to prove log 2 base 10 <= 0.301 other than verifying the value using a calculator? Please give a detailed explanation, if proof is possible.

Comment: Not an answer, but we can cheaply get a good approximation. Since $2^{10}$ is a little bigger than $10^3$, but not much bigger, we know that $10\log_{10} 2$ is a little bigger than $3$, so $\log_{10} 2$ is a little bigger than $0.3$.

Answer (score 2):

But it's not.

It is 0.30102999...

Answer (score 0):

Yes an approximate let $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=2$ thus $x=1/3$ and then using taylor series for $log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})=2(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}+..)$